# Tag managers for Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-instant-articles

Is it possible to use tag managers such as Tealium or Google tag manager when creating a facebook instant article?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Official documentation is saying:

> You can embed HTML/JavaScript tracking code within an iframe on each article using the Analytics element. Anything in this iframe will execute at the beginning of each article load

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/analytics

That means, all that you need to do, is just place your GTM or Tealium tag